# Excel WorksheetFunction.Or

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

Does `WorksheetFunction.Or` evaluate all arguments, or does it immediately return `True` once an argument evaluates to `True`?

The thing is, I am trying to check if a variable is numeric, and if it is, I want to check if it is less than 1. You can see it below:

```
If IsNumeric(lvl) Or lvl < 1 Then
    Do sth...
End If
```

Described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx), the `Or` operator in VBA evaluates all arguments and I get Type Mismatch Error when `_lvl_` is not numeric. Does `WorksheetFunction.Or` behave the same?

Comment: I know VBA does not have lazy OR, but the Excel worksheet functions are all really written in C and are quite optimized.  I would define some UDFs in VBA that have side effects (like showing a message box) and then run three of them through an OR function to test this.

Comment: I think you want to use `And` instead of `Or` in your example. It's still the same issue though.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Yeah, you are right. Just wanted to make up an example, a bad example. Thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `WorksheetFunction.Or` behaves the same.

The reason being, it is a regular function as far as VBA is concerned, so VBA will evaluate all arguments before passing them to the function. The function will not have a chance to perform lazy evaluation.

In order for lazy evaluation to kick in, the evaluation construct must be a part of the language syntax. VBA does not have it in its syntax, so it's not going to work when calling any function in any way.

Comment: Interesting, so even if the worksheet function would use lazy evaluation, calling it from VBA wouldn't help?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct You can't make that conclusion based on the fact that this is how it works on the VBA side. It might very well work differently on the Excel side, because an Excel formula called from a sheet is a different language/syntax that might support short circuiting. It does not support it in reality, but that's not because VBA also does not support it.